NavigationLink doesn't work inside of sheet view
I created a few buttons inside of a sheet view
struct PlusMenu: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var scaleChange = true
    var buttons = ["cup.and.saucer", "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw", "carrot", "fork.knife","equal.square"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Cancel")
                        .font(customFont(20, "-Black"))
                })
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(.top)
            }
            
            LabelledDivider(label: "Actions")
            
            Spacer()
            buttonList(start:0, end: 3)
            buttonList(start:3, end:buttons.count)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    func buttonList(start:Int, end:Int) -> some View{
        HStack{
            ForEach(buttons[start..<end], id:\.self){ buttonName in
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Enter")
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: buttonName)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Circle().stroke(.semiGray, lineWidth: 3).shadow(radius: 3))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }

                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical)
    }
}

This is my view for sheet

But the main problem is when I click the button, it doesn't navigate to the next destination page. it works in the preview but not on device.
And I don't have navigationStack in this page is because I have that at my root view.
Do we allow to have navigationLink inside of sheet view?

AFAIK, sheet need their own NavigationStack. So
in your .sheet(...), try using:
 .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
     NavigationStack {  // <--- here
         PlusMenu()
     }
 }

Alternatively you could try using NavigationStack(path: $navPath), see:
NavigationStack. Passing the navPath to the .sheet(item: $navPath)

you can use navigation view in bottom sheet for navigation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var isSheetPresented = false

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         VStack {
            Button("Open Bottom Sheet") {
                isSheetPresented = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
                BottomSheetView()
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Main View")
    }
  }
}

struct BottomSheetView: View {

   @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
   @State var scaleChange = true
   var buttons = ["cup.and.saucer", "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw", "carrot", "fork.knife","equal.square"]

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
          VStack {
              Text("This is a Bottom Sheet")
               NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Image(systemName: "buttonName")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 3).shadow(radius: 3))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                Spacer()
                buttonList(start:0, end: 3)
                buttonList(start:3, end:buttons.count)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Bottom Sheet")
    }
}

func buttonList(start:Int, end:Int) -> some View{
    HStack{
        ForEach(buttons[start..<end], id:\.self){ buttonName in
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Enter")
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: buttonName)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Circle().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 3).shadow(radius: 3))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .padding(.vertical)
   }
}

 struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
       Text("This is the Second View")
           .navigationTitle("Second View")
    }
  }

 struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       ContentView()
   }
 }

